# What's this monoline geometric slab serif font?

Tags: font-identification

It looks like an avant garde, but with small differencies on the edges.

Do you have any clue if there is a font specific or it is a variation done by human hand?

[image]

Comment: Based on a [WhatTheFont Search](http://www.WhattheFont.com), it appears to be based on this font: http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic/ext-lit/.

I tried to find fonts which were based on this one, but I haven't been able to find anything, so I'm not sure if those are hand-modified letters or an actual font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its RNS camelia

[image]

You can get this font here : [RNS camelia](http://www.dafont.com/rns-camelia.font)

Comment: That's most definitely it!